# Parameterized query doesn't work, no errors

Tags: c#, sqlite

Why doesn't the following query doesn't return any results? it gives no errors.

```
SQLiteCommand sqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE @COL LIKE @searchKey", DataBaseConnnection);
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add("@searchKey", DbType.String).Value = SearchKeyWord;
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add("@COL", DbType.String).Value = COLString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to pass in a column name as a parameter, you can't do that.  That query is comparing the *literal* value of the `@COL` parameter against the `@searchKey` pattern.  It's perfectly legal syntax, but doesn't work life you want it to.

I suspect what you want is:

```
SQLiteCommand sqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table 
                                              + " WHERE " + COLString 
                                              + " LIKE @searchKey", DataBaseConnnection);
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add("@searchKey", DbType.String).Value = SearchKeyWord;
```

However you should ONLY do this if you have COMPLETE control of the strings that can be passed in - otherwise you're open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: that's the reason why I was trying to pass it as a parameter, I guess I should filter out the string first.

Comment: a quick question, is it possible to select any column? * doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not that I know of - I'm not a SQLite expert but other systems that I DO know don't allow wildcard column selection.